# Instantiating class and passing action

Tags: php

I'm working through a PHP starter book I just got along with code. I am stuck on this one example and I have no idea what's going on. Can someone help explain what is going on?

This class seems to get instantiated and the default case is to list the posts recorded to a database:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/admin.php');

$admin_posts = new Posts;
```

When the class gets called, the default case loads options to pass the id and action to the php file above, then it will parse and call another method. In my case, i'm trying to delete a post, but I keep getting an error that says object not found.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('database.php');
class Adminpanel{
    public function __construct(){
        $inactive = 600;
        if (isset($_SESSION["kickstart_login"])) {
            $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
            if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
                header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/login.php?status=inactive");
            }
        }
        $_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
        $login = $_SESSION['kickstart_login'];
        if(empty($login)){
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/login.php?status=loggedout');
        }else{
            $this->ksdb = new Database;
            $this->base = (object) '';
            $this->base->url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        }
    }
}

class Posts extends Adminpanel{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!empty($_GET['action'])){
            switch ($_GET['action']){
                case 'create':
                    $this->addPost();
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->listPosts();
                    break;
                case 'save':
                    $this->savePost();
                    break;
                case 'edit':
                    echo "string";
                    $this->editPosts();
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    $this->deletePost();
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            $this->listPosts();
        }
    }

    public function listPosts(){
        $posts = $return = array();
        $query = $this->ksdb->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
        try {
            $query->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
                $return[$i] = array();
                foreach($row as $key => $rowitem){
                    $return[$i][$key] = $rowitem;
                }
            }
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $posts = $return;
        require_once('templates/manageposts.php');
    }

    public function editPosts(){
        echo "string";
    }

    public function addPost(){
        require_once('templates/newpost.php');
    }

    public function savePost(){
        $status= '';
        $array = $format = $return = array();
        if(!empty($_POST['post'])){
            $post = $_POST['post'];
        }
        if(!empty($post['content'])){
            $array['content'] = $post['content'];
            $format[] = ':content'; 
        }
        if(!empty($post['title'])){
            $array['title'] = $post['title'];
            $format[] = ':title'; 
        } 
        $cols = $values = '';
        $i=0;
        foreach($array as $col => $data){
            if($i==0){
                $cols .= $col;
                $values .= $format[$i];
            }else{
                $cols .= ','.$col;
                $values .= ','.$format[$i];
            }
            $i++;
        }
        try {
            $query = $this->ksdb->db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(".$cols.") VALUES (".$values.")");
            for($c=0;$c<$i;$c++){
                $query->bindParam($format[$c], ${'var'.$c});
            }
            $z=0;
            foreach($array as $col => $data){
                ${'var' . $z} = $data;
                $z++;
            }
            $result = $query->execute();
            $add = $query->rowCount();
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $query->closeCursor();
        $this->db = null;
        if(!empty($add) && $add > 0){
            $status = array('success' => 'Your post has been saved successfully.');
            $key = 'success';
        }else{
            $status = array('error' => 'There has been an error saving your post. Please try again later.');
            $key = 'error';
        }
        header("Location: ".$this->base->url."/posts.php?status=".$key);        
    }

    public function deletePost(){
        echo "string";
        // if(!empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
        //  $query = "DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
        //  $result = $this->db->query($query);
        //  $delete = $result->rowCount();
        //  $this->db = null;
        //  if(!empty($delete) && $delete > 0){
        //      header("Location: ".$this->base->url."/posts.php?delete=success");
        //  }else{
        //      header("Location: ".$this->base->url."/posts.php?delete=error");
        //  }
        // }    
    }

}

class Comments extends Adminpanel{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete'){
            $this->deleteComment();
        }else{
            $this->listComments();
        }
    }

    public function listComments(){
        $comments = $return = array();
        $query = $this->ksdb->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments");
        try {
            $query->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
                $return[$i] = array();
                foreach($row as $key => $rowitem){
                    $return[$i][$key] = $rowitem;
                }
            }
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $comments = $return;
        require_once('templates/managecomments.php');
    }

    public function deleteComment(){
        if(!empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
            $query = "DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
            $result = $this->db->query($query);
            $delete = $result->rowCount();
            $this->db = null;
            if(!empty($delete) && $delete > 0){
                header("Location: ".$this->base->url."/comments.php?delete=success");
            }else{
                header("Location: ".$this->base->url."/comments.php?delete=error");
            }
        }   
    }

}

$admin = new Adminpanel();
```

Comment: what is `$this->db` variable? where is set, why do you use it instead of ksdb and why do you set it to null?

Comment: For reference, this framework is abusing the hell out of constructors.  `new Posts` shouldn't be doing near as much work as it's being made to.

Comment: Not my code. I dont know. I replaced this->db to match ksdb for result=$this->ksdb->db->query($query); and commented out this->db out, but still doesn't work

Comment: I've had a the worst time with this book, but I need to get this type of example working for my site. Can you recommend something like a blog where I can post new entries and have others comment?

Comment: jump start php - it is from sitepoint and they have the code online. Most of all the code I used had to be modified with new references to files, etc.

Comment: I'm fairly certain every PHP framework in existence has a tutorial somewhere on how to build a blog with it.  Laravel and CakePHP do, i know.

Comment: I wasted too much time on this book and i got nothing out of it.

Comment: I'd so get a refund.  Apparently they have a 30-day money back thing.  If the code is any indication, the book is probably teaching you every bad habit i hate about PHP noobs.

Comment: I don't even know where to get started with PHP. I know there are major blogging platforms like wordpress and drupal, but I wanted to learn from the ground up. What is a good approach to learn principal conecpts, but learn things eventually to swithc over to using a cms (because that's what everyone else does?)

Comment: Probably the best approach would be mentoring.  At least if there were enough non-crappy PHP programmers willing to help, or you happened to know one.  Short of that, i don't know.  Some other form of learning by example, maybe.  But i don't think i've ever seen a PHP book that didn't suck big fat hairy coconuts through a mile-long coffee stirrer.  If you go the book route, you'll need at least 3, and probably more.